# Automatic capitalization of section headings

Tags: titles, capitalization

I have a large project (report class) in which I am importing separate files.
What I would like to do is capitalise each word in the titles of chapter/section/subsection in the main document and table of contents just as how normally book titles are organized. How would I achieve the desired outputs (please see at the bottom of the post) within the report class?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{import} 
% For subsubsection in report class
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% LINE SPACING
\newcommand{\linespacing}{1.5}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\linespacing}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pagestyle{plain}
% ANY OTHER DECLARATIONS HERE:
%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% HYPERREF
\usepackage[colorlinks,pagebackref,pdfusetitle,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=blue,bookmarksnumbered,plainpages=false]{hyperref}

% For capitalization of all label names throughout the document (not working)

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

% TABLE OF CONTENTS, LISTS OF TABLES & FIGURES
\newpage
\pdfbookmark[0]{Contents}{contents_bookmark}
\tableofcontents
%%%%%%%%%%

\chapter{Introduction}
\input{file1}
    
\end{document}
```

In file1.tex, I have these.

```
    \section{section file1}\label{file1}
    \subsection{capital letter for first letters except for `and', `in', `for', etc.}
    \subsubsection{the theory of everything}
    \subsubsection{how it works}
    \subsubsection{relationship between A and B}
```

The desired outcome would be
[image]
[image]

Comment: What exactly do you expect `cleveref` to be capitalizing? the `capitalize` option is designed to make the name of the element being referred to with a `\cref` capitalized, i.e. "Table 1" instead of "table 1", "Section 1" instead of "section 1". It doesn't capitalize the section titles themselves. Perhaps you're looking for a solution like this: [Capitalising first letter of each word in section headings using book class](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/120718)

Comment: As @AlanMunn has already noted in a comment, `cleveref` is *not* the right tool for the job. Please be more specific about the extent of capitalization you need LaTeX to perform: Do you need all letters of every word in chapter and sectioning headers to be capitalized, or just the first letters of each word? Put differently, do you need `\section{Section File1}` to produce `1.1 SECTION FILE1` or `1.1 Section File1`? Please advise.

Comment: @Alan Munn thank you for pointing out my misunderstandings.

Comment: @Mico thank you for the comments. I updated my original post to make the point clearer.

Comment: For this kind of capitalization see: [Capitalizing strings ignoring closed class words](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/34796) although I suspect it's simpler just to do it yourself as you type. You can use the `titlesec` package to use this command in your sectioning commands.

Comment: When you say "capitalize" do you mean the whole word, or the first letter only, excluding predesignates like "and", "or", etc.  If the latter, perhaps the titlecaps package can help.